# How to generate similar data samples from data streams using joint probability distribution?

Tags: sampling, dataset, joint-distribution, distance-functions

I want to generate a small block of data samples (used for classification) from a data stream but, its joint probability distribution should be different than the given data stream. Is it possible to use distance function to reverse engineer the problem?